# What happened to my "Electorate" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I've just got [Electorate badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) on Stack Overflow.

> [image]

But it is not displaying in my badges. Badge count is also not increasing. :'(

Comment: @Dronehinge Already did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> multiple times on Chrome (Windows).

Comment: @shashwat server side caching. Nothing you can do about it. See my answer.

Comment: And a dup from the mod-deleted http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259016/245360. Not sure why it was deleted actually.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't have that privilege to view  deleted questions on Meta yet. :p

Comment: @PatrickHofman exact dupe vs possbile. Also animuson's answer says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by caching. The new user profile determines if you *most likely* would be awarded with the badge, and shows it to you.

After a while, the server side process kicks in that does the actually awarding of badges. This makes your badges definitive. Until that time, you can see it in your profile as 'awarded', but it really gets awarded afterwards. Then all the count, etc. gets updated.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thanks

Comment: In meantime, can I see it somewhere else in profile? like `pending process` or something like this ?

Comment: @shashwat No. Nothing you can see or do.

Comment: Actually, I can see it http://i.imgur.com/94ibyt7.png under badge tracking settings.

Comment: @shashwat Indeed. That is the new profile page part. That part shows the 'unofficial' view, it will be fully awarded once the process ran.

Comment: Okay @patrick. Thanks for your answer.